# Intercept data from post request with api platform

Tags: api, symfony, post, request, api-platform.com

It's my first post here: after hours of research on web I decided to ask here if someone have the answer.

-> I m working on a symfony app and I have just started using api platform and would like to know if it is possible (I guess so) to "intercept" post requests to process their content. I would like to be able to compare the contents of a table with the contents of the query. The final goal is to be able to authenticate devices if their activation code is in the table in question.
Hope this is understandable ...

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible Api platform have some events and you can listen one of them see https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/
In your case I will listen POST_DESERIALIZE

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i ll investigate :)

Comment: If It helped you, you can upvote or accept this answer :)